# Question on dual spaces of vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $k$ be a field. Also let $E$ and $F$ be finite dimensional $k$ vector spaces.

What are the most general conditions for $k$, $E$ and $F$ under which a $k$-bilinear form $\langle\;,\;\rangle :E\times F \to k$ gives rise to an isomorphism $E\cong \text{Hom}_k(F.k)$?

I know that if $\langle\;,\;\rangle$ is non-degenerate on the left and $\text{dim}E=\text{dim}F$ then an isomorphism exists. But are these the weakest possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: The condition $\dim E= \dim F$ is certainly sufficient. It is also necessary, as $\dim \operatorname{Hom} _k(F,k)=\dim F\times \dim k = \dim F$.